# Webpack and webpack-dev-server installation error

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to install a Webpack and Babel to use React without CRA.

During installation **webpack-dev-server**, I've facing with some dependencies problems

```
PS C:\Users\Lebedev\Desktop\projects\frontend-graduation-project> npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     dev babel-loader@"^8.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.27.0 || ^5.0.0" from css-loader@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/css-loader
npm ERR!     dev css-loader@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (html-webpack-plugin, style-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware
npm ERR!   webpack-dev-middleware@"^3.7.2" from webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/webpack-dev-server
npm ERR!     dev webpack-dev-server@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Lebedev\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lebedev\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-15T12_42_34_324Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Lebedev\Desktop\projects\frontend-graduation-project>
```

My package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

What I already did and it still not help:

1. Tried remove node_modules folder
2. Tried remove package-lock.json file
3. Reinstall npm dependencies by running this command: **npm install**

How to solve this problems?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer on a Github Issue page: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2119

My npm version has been 7.0.8. As a mvyunko mention in issue, I just type the following:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

After all commands, my npm version has been changed to 6.14.8, and installation error has gone.